# Trouble with model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

The goal is for a shop to create rewards and associate each reward to a follower of his choice. This is my setup:

```
class Shop < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rewards
  has_many :follows
  has_many :users, through: :follows
end

class Reward < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shop
end

class Follow < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shop
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :reward_participant
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :follows
  has_many :shops, through: :follows
end
```

I created this model in order to capture the reward and follower association.

```
class RewardParticipant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :reward
  belongs_to :follow
end
```

And I have created the following migrations:

```
class CreateRewards < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :rewards do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :body
      t.date :expires
      t.integer :shope_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class CreateRewardParticipants < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :reward_participants do |t|
      t.integer :reward_id
      t.integer :follow_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I'm having trouble figuring out if this is the correct approach to the model associations and migrations. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: what is Follow over here?

Comment: Hey @Gagan Gupta... it is for whoever follows the shop!

Comment: Okay, your design is okay but why there is a need of follow in RewardParticipant.You can have user and reward because reward already belongs to a  particular shop

Comment: So basically you're suggesting to remove the follow associations from `Follow` and `RewardParticipant` because I can use the `User` and `Review` association?

Comment: Keep the `RewardParticipant` and remove `Follow` because Follow isn't helping you in this scenario. 
if you want to get `user.rewards` how are you going to fetch the rewards?

Comment: If you want to get `shop.reward_participants` with all the user details then that's also a overhead of getting data through follower table

Comment: What do you mean by keep and remove?? The models or the associations inside them models?

Comment: remove follow association inside `reward_participants` and replace `follow` with `user`
and check whether all your requirements are being fulfilled?

Comment: Thank you @Gagan Gupta, I will try it out and let you know!

Comment: sure, not a problem @Dev

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally you are right.

We want users to follow a shop, and a shop can create rewards and grant many rewards to many followers.

## 1. Visual schema:

[image]

## 2. Model associations (complete version)

user.rb

```
has_many :follows
has_many :reward_follows, through: :follows
has_many :rewards, through: :reward_follows # NOT through shops
has_many :shops, through: :follows
```

follow.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :shop
has_many :reward_follows
```

shop.rb

```
has_many :rewards
has_many :reward_follows, through: :rewards # NOT through follows
has_many :follows
has_many :users, through: :follows
```

reward.rb

```
has_many :reward_follows
belongs_to :shop
has_many :follows, through: :reward_follows
has_many :users, through: :follows
```

## 3. Do not use date field. Use datetime field.

Justification: https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/time-without-date/194146

This personally saved me hours of work long-term.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Yshmarov. :)))) How about the `reward_follows` model associations. You forgot about them.

Comment: Also I think that these two associations `has_many :follows, through: : reward_follows`
 `has_many :users, through: :follows` inside the rewards model are wrong!!!

Comment: `reward_follows` has just the `belongs_to` associations

Comment: `has_many :follows, through: : reward_follows` is a basic `has many through`, where `reward_follows` is a simple joint table. Imagine "`user` has many `tags` through `user_tags`"

Comment: `has_many :users, through: :follows` - looks legit in theory. worth trying. tell me if it works in practice !

Comment: Thanks @Yshmarov!

Comment: hope it helps. would be cool if you shared the git repo of your solution :)